# Passing multiple values to SSRS using MDX

Tags: reporting-services, mdx, ssrs-2012

I am running the following command for getting a multi value report

```
StrToSet
("[Dim Branch].[HierarchyB-T-C].[Trading Code].&[" + 
Replace(
Join(
Parameters!TradingName.Value,"],"
) +"]",",",",[Dim Branch].[HierarchyB-T-C].[Trading Code].&["),",")
```

But I'm getting an error

> 'The Syntax for 'Join' is incorrect'.

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Can anyone correct me please?

If I change it to `StrToSet(@TradingName, Constrained)` it works for single value, but I'd like to pass multiple values.

Comment: Have you set the TradingName parameter to allow multiple values? And what is the error you get when sending multiple values using the simple method. As far as I know there should be no issues using a multi value param with the StrToSet function. We might also need to see the full MDX you are using in your report query..

Comment: Kalim you are right, if i tick on multiple value in TradingName parameter and use only StrToSet(@TradingName, Constrained), it works fine for multiple value as well in SSRS reporting environment . However, i actually tried to pass comma separated multiple value if i get succeed to do this, i will be able to pass those in DATA DRIVEN SUBSCRIPTION that's my ultimate goal. i found some trick to pass multiple values  in DATA DRIVEN SUBSCRIPTION in T-SQL but i am struggling fit those into my MDX, Do you know about that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you trying to do now, especially if you are trying to use a data driven subscription. Remember that a data driven subscription uses a master query, and for every record returned by the master query your report will execute. Its not clear what you are trying to do anymore...

Comment: Did my answer help you find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass multiple value from parameter, i just followed the steps
1 Add parameters and name it like 
[image]

2. Under dataset properties (shared dataset properties as well) , the Parameters tab write an expression like this way
   =Split(Parameters!TradingName.Value,",")
   [image]

[image]

3. in Shared dataset, write the MDX with  **WHERE (StrToSet(@TradingName))**

```js
SELECT 
     {[Total]} ON COLUMNS 
 ,
  {
 [Dim Account].[Account Type].&[Income] 
 }
 *
    STRTOMEMBER("[Dim Fiscal Year].[HierarchyFiscal].[E Month].&[" + @FiscalYear +"]&[" + FORMAT(Now(),"MMMM") +"].PREVMEMBER")  
 *
  ORDER
  (
  {
  [Dim Branch].[Branch Name].[Branch Name]
  },[Total], BDESC
  )
  ON ROWS
from [CubeProfitLoss]
WHERE (StrToSet(@TradingName))
```

4. when you want to preview the multiple value, make sure you are using , to separate trading name likewise
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you need curly braces to form a set? I have added one at the start of the below ... a little unsure where the end of your string is - does it end like this `.&["`?!

```
StrToSet(
   "{[Dim Branch].[HierarchyB-T-C].[Trading Code].&[" 
   + 
   Replace(
      Join(Parameters!TradingName.Value,"],") + "]"
    , ","
    , ",[Dim Branch].[HierarchyB-T-C].[Trading Code].&["
   )
   ,","
 )
```

If `Parameters!TradingName.Value` is equal to a string of this format `MEC,RSA` then maybe `join` is not required:

```
StrToSet(
  "{" 
  +
  Replace(
    "[Dim Branch].[HierarchyB-T-C].[Trading Code].&[" 
    + 
    Parameters!TradingName.Value
   , ","
   ,"],[Dim Branch].[HierarchyB-T-C].[Trading Code].&["
  )
  +
  "]}"
 ,constrained)
```

Comment: Sorry whytheg, it didn't' work same 'The Syntax for 'Join' is incorrect' appreared. But thanks for trying to help me

Comment: @SHAMIM can you please supply an example of the string `Parameters!TradingName.Value`

Comment: @SHAMIM I've just rearranged your statement onto seperate lines  - is this just code you've copied from somewhere?!

Comment: the example of string is MEC,RSA its actually the TradingCode of Trading Table.

Comment: Yes you are right i copied it from http://erikasblog.datainspirations.com/2010/01/21/passing-multi-value-sql-parameters-to-an-mdx-query-in-reporting-services/ then edited with " " this thing

Comment: did you see my comment i posted to Kalim's answer, if not please follow it for my ultimate goal

Comment: I tried  your rearranged code, same JOIN issue, sorry

Comment: (I just rearranged purely so I could get an idea of what was happening)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94874/discussion-between-shamim-and-whytheq).

Comment: @SHAMIM just tested my second script and it seems to run ok...?